# Merging two image - overlaying (javascript)

Tags: javascript, image, merge, background-color

I'm struggling with one of my main function which consists of applying the selected color to an image. My original idea was to place a determined image behind the image generated after the color change to make a new one (by "merging" the two). Buuuut, while struggling with is idea, I decided to just apply a colored background to the image after the color change to make a new one. For that purpose I used ctx fillstyle but nothing works -_-.

```
function applyColorToImages() {
    const images = document.querySelectorAll('.original-image');
    imageContainer.innerHTML = ''; // Supprimer les images précédentes

    images.forEach((image, index) => {
      const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
      const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
      canvas.width = image.width;
      canvas.height = image.height;


      ctx.filter = `hue-rotate(${selectedColor})`;
      ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);


    ctx.fillStyle = '#FD0';

      const modifiedImgUrl = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
      const modifiedImg = document.createElement('img');
      modifiedImg.src = modifiedImgUrl;
      modifiedImg.classList.add('modified-image');
      imageContainer.appendChild(modifiedImg);
```

Any idea ? :)

(If you have solutions for the first idea I would be grateful too!)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)